# MongoDb client set proxy

Tags: mongodb, client

I'm using MongoDB client in `mongodb-driver-sync:4.0.1`, however I can't find a way to set proxy for this client (my db is located on machine behind proxy). How to address this issue? Is there a way to set it on lower level?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB drivers connect to the server directly. If you figure out a way to hijack this connection and reroute it through the proxy transparently to the driver, this could work, but I am unaware of any way to configure MongoDB drivers to use a proxy.